# From Russia With Love

Tags: cipher, chess

MI6 has discovered a recently activated Soviet Sleeper Cell operating in London, they've given the task to you to determine where, when, and how they will strike.

You come across the location of their last known meeting, the trail is several hours cold, but they've left a chessboard out looking like this.

[image: Chess Game]

A book is open to a historical game: Spassky v. Bronstein, Leningrad, 1960
complete with movelist and analysis.
(For your convenience, the move list follows):

> 1.e4 e5
> 2.f4 exf4
> 3.Nf3 d5
> 4.exd5 Bd6
> 5.Nc3 Ne7
> 6.d4 0-0
> 7.Bd3 Nd7
> 8.0-0 h6
> 9.Ne4 Nxd5
> 10.c4 Ne3
> 11.Bxe3 fxe3
> 12.c5 Be7
> 13.Bc2 Re8
> 14.Qd3 e2
> 15.Nd6 Nf8
> 16.Nxf7 exf1Q+
> 17.Rxf1 Bf5
> 18.Qxf5 Qd7
> 19.Qf4 Bf6
> 20.N3e5 Qe7
> 21.Bb3 Bxe5
> 22.Nxe5+ Kh7
> 23.Qe4+ Kh8 1-0

You can tell it's the game for which the end position is on the board.

In the trash you find a crumpled index card, one side covered with mysterious writing.

> S1R23R23S9s2p22 S9R23 S10S1S18P20
> s19r6P17P20S7P5S3R23R8P15 s2p13S6S2S6p5R23
> s13P22R23S5p13S1R18

Hint:

> The method of encyphering is one->many, in database terms, however each symbol in the ciphertext decodes to exactly one symbol in plaintext, depending on the key used.

After several hours of investigation, you receive a call from your superiors.

> Be careful, we have reason to believe this group has acquired a dangerous spore-based biological agent they may use in this attack.

Comment: Jame Austem, the fanous movelist.

Comment: I have verified that (1) those are indeed the moves of a famous game played between those players on that date and (2) it is *almost* the right final position (the actual final position has the black king on h7, not h8). The contents of the index card look superficially like Forsyth-Edwards notation for a chess position (presumably with S=knight as is customary in many European countries) but clearly aren't actually quite that.

Comment: I have seen the game in question called "The SMERSH Gambit" which kinda fits with the title and theme of this puzzle.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan strikes again!

Comment: ... and this very game (with some gratuitous errors, perhaps because someone thought there was a copyright issue) features in the movie "From Russia With Love". White receives a message saying "You are required at once" near the end of the game, finishes it off and (I assume) goes off to do some spyish thing.

Comment: ... To be more precise about the discrepancy between puzzle and reality: the puzzle has Black playing ...Kh8 where in fact I think he just resigned, and of course that's why the diagram has the king on h8 instead of h7.

Comment: Yeah, I based it off the underlying game from "From Russia With Love" as told by this site: http://en.chessbase.com/portals/4/files/games/2004/bond.htm It has black move Kh8 followed by his resignation.

Comment: However, the fact that it's this game is primarily flavor, the encryption method I've chosen could work on any game in theory, although in practice that's much less true.

Comment: On a point of pedantry with respect to the back story: it should be MI5, who do domestic counterintelligence, not 6, who do foreign espionage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is:

> ATTACK AT DAWN MORNINGTON CRESCENT ANTHRAX

and the cipher works as follows:

> The spaces in the ciphertext are actual spaces. The material in between is a sequence of things like "P12" or "s19", each of which corresponds to one plaintext letter. In each:
>  - The number picks out one pair of moves in the chess game.
>  - The case of the letter indicates whether to look at White's move (for capitals P,R,S) or Black's (for lowercase p,r,s).
>  - The letter indicates which of three ways the plaintext letter is represented:
>  P,p indicate that it's given by the *piece* moved (K,Q,R,B,N,P);
>  R,r indicate that it's given by the *kind of move* (O for castling, written O-O or O-O-O; X for capture, written x; T for a check, written + which looks a bit like a lowercase t);
>  S,s indicate that it's given by the *square* moved to. See below for the details of this.

The Snn letters determinable from the above are:

> `a b c d e f g h
>  . . . . A . . . 8
>  . . . . . . . . 7
>  . . . . . M . . 6
>  . . . . . W . . 5
>  . . D E A C . . 4
>  . . H . . G . . 3
>  . . S . . . . . 2
>  . . . . . . . . 1`

and M Oehm, who is *so much* smarter than I am, observes in comments that

> if we *delete from the alphabet the letters that already have other representations* via pieces and move types (i.e., KQRBNP and TXO) and identify I and J in the usual way, we have just enough letters left to fill a 4x4 square ... and lo, they fit very nicely:

> `a b c d e f g h
>  A C D E A C D E 8
>  F G H I F G H I 7
>  L M S U L M S U 6
>  V W Y Z V W Y Z 5
>  A C D E A C D E 4
>  F G H I F G H I 3
>  L M S U L M S U 2
>  V W Y Z V W Y Z 1`

And with that, all is explained.

> A few worked examples. `R23`, which occurs several times, means: look at move 23; look at *White's* move 23 because `R` is a capital letter; observe that it's a check and therefore corresponds to letter T. `s1` means: look at move 1; look at *Black's* move 1 because `s` is a lowercase letter; observe that on move 1 Black moved to e5 corresponding to the letter V. (There happens to be no V in the message.) And `P7` means: look at white's move 7, observe it's made by a bishop, so the letter is B.

Comment: The omitted letter is intentional, it cannot be encoded with this key, but the meaning of the text remains obvious regardless. I appear to have made an error in Word 4 that has now been corrected (S5->S7) I've gone back and double-checked everything else, and they decode correctly.

Comment: Correction: There is an encoding for the missing letter that I managed to miss repeatedly. It would have been S13, but it is not required to make sense of the message.

Comment: The 17 letters that aren't pieces or move types are `A.CDEFGHIJ.LM.....S.UVW.YZ`. You can group them in four groups of four: `ACDE`, `FGHI`, `LMSU` and `VWYZ` with the Playfair convention that I and J are encoded the same. Arrange them in a 4×4 square and put that square on the board four times. (Your sketch is very helpful and this method explains why both e4 and e8 decode to `A`.)

Comment: Ah! It never occurred to me to delete the ones that have other encodings. D'oh!

Comment: _who is so much smarter than I am_ - er, no. I've added only the last bit to a puzzle that you've solved pretty much alone and that I couldn't get into when I tried to tackle it.

Comment: You probably tried to tackle it without the hint that basically gave away what one of the words was :-).